# Joining Multiple MySQL tables with Same Column Name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 tables and have a column exists in each table, like this:

```
table 1:(profile) Customer,
table 2: (Order) OrderID, Customer, Amount, Charges, Date
table 3: (cancel) cancelID, Customer, Amount, Charges, Date
```

I am trying to calculate the amount and charges of each customers by joining 3 tables. But the amount and charges of cancel table were added to the amount and charges from Order table. Here's the sample mysql query I tried:

```
Select c.Customer,
FORMAT((CASE WHEN o.Date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN COUNT(o.OrderID) ELSE 0 END),0) as qty,
FORMAT((CASE WHEN o.Date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN SUM(o.Amount) ELSE 0 END),2) as Total_Amount,
FORMAT((CASE WHEN o.Date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN SUM(o.Charges) ELSE 0 END),2) as charges
FORMAT((CASE WHEN cc.Date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN COUNT(cc.cancelID) ELSE 0 END),0) as qty_cancel,
FORMAT((CASE WHEN cc.Date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN SUM(cc.Amount) ELSE 0 END),2) as Total_cancel,
FORMAT((CASE WHEN cc.Date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' THEN SUM(cc.Charges) ELSE 0 END),2) as charges_cancel
from profile c LEFT JOIN order o t ON c.Customer=o.Customer
LEFT JOIN cancel cc ON c.Customer=cc.customer GROUP BY c.Customer
```

Here's the desired output:

```
| Customer   | Qty  | Total    | Charges    | Qty  | Total   | Charges   |
| User 1     | 13   | 5,000.00 |  500.00    |  1   | -200.00 | -50.00    |
| User 2     |  5   | 1,000.00 |  100.00    |  0   |  0.00   |  0.00     |
```

Any help will truly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: I think your mistake is here `THEN SUM(c.Amount)`: it should be `THEN SUM(cc.Amount)`. The very same mistake with `c.charges` that should be `cc.charges`.
Why do you use `c` for table profile? Wouldn't it be better using `p` so to avoid confusion?

Comment: You've written `c.Charges` etc but c is the profile table and does not contain Charges. You aliased cancel table as cc

Comment: I think your mistake is having two tables with essentially the same structure, instead of just one table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this slight reorganisation:

```
Select 
  p.Customer,
  O.*,
  C.*
from 
  profile P
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      Customer, 
      COUNT(OrderID) as qty,
      SUM(Amount) as Total_Amount,
      SUM(Charges) as charges 
    FROM order 
    WHERE Date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' 
    GROUP BY Customer
  ) o ON p.Customer=o.Customer 

  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      Customer, 
      COUNT(OrderID) as qty_cancel,
      SUM(Amount) as Total_Amount_cancel,
      SUM(Charges) as charges_cancel 
    FROM cancel
    WHERE Date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' 
    GROUP BY Customer
  ) c ON p.Customer=C.Customer
```

I removed the format for clarity but you can add it back in if you need

I recommend you do the grouping and summing in sub queries so that they only output one row per customer. If you try doing it all as a same level query and you have eg 2 rows for order and 2 rows for cancel you'll end up multiplying the rows to 4 rows which then throws your totals off when you group and sum. By grouping as a subquery and having one row per customer you avoid this problem (it's called a Cartesian explosion)